# The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well formed

Tags: android

Error : The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.  How do I correct it ?

I have just started using eclipse and am building myfirstapp as per the instructions on developer.android.com.

```
<<<<<<<  Original
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myFirstApp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myFirstApp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


=======
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
>>>>>>> Added
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the '<<<<<<<  Original', the '=======', and the '>>>>>>> Added'. Those were most likely put there by a merge tool.

Make sure you keep the '' at the top of the file. For the rest, I don't know which parts from the original you want (the part at the top) and your new entries (below the '=======').