# YoutubeAPI The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android, youtube-api

[I just spread the errors but the main error still there :( still no solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGMVr.png)

C:\MagicSaloons\app\src\main\res\libs\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar:1:2: Error: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > C:\MagicSaloons\app\src\main\res\libs\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar:1:2: Error: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
  at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
  at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
  Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: C:\MagicSaloons\app\src\main\res\libs\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar:1:2: Error: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:166)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:88)
  at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
  ... 78 more
  Caused by: C:\MagicSaloons\app\src\main\res\libs\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar:1:2: Error: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
  at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergingException.throwIfNonEmpty(MergingException.java:152)
  at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataSet.loadFromFiles(DataSet.java:257)
  at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.loadFromFiles(ResourceSet.java:53)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:136)
  ... 85 more

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.443 secs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.danutneagu.magicsaloons">

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignupActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".CoaforServicesList"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ImageList">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Contact"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ImageList2">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CoaforServicesList2"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutUs"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".VideoViewActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Deals"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Gallery"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Blog"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WorkWithUs"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Newsletter"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CoaforServicesAndProductsSearch">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".YoutubeActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Hello, everyone, I got this issue every time I want to clean/rebuild/build/compile/ and I'm literally stuck because I'm a kind of new developer.The main problem is to make YoutubeAPI work.

I was lucky just 1 time worked without error but after I tried to compile it returned to the same error.

It's really annoying. Any idea it's welcomed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876697/the-markup-in-the-document-preceding-the-root-element-must-be-well-formed), make sure you keep the `"` at the top of the file. Also as stated in this [documentation](https://www.w3resource.com/xml/proper-nesting-of-elements.php), This markup would be wrong if the elements weren't nested properly. Nesting of xml elements must be proper, in a well-formed xml document. A validating xml parser will generate an error if it is not following the rules set by the DTD properly.